# How can I set up a route with VPN and expose an extra WIFI, pretending to be in another country

Tags: vpn, router

I live away from my country of birth, but frequently consume content from my old home country, where a lot of the content is geo-restricted. I am able to access it using a VPN, which is fine, but I would like an easier solution, also for other members of the household.

Here is what I am considering doing:

1. Get a router, which supports VPN
2. Configure it to be logged onto VPN with an exit in my home country (always)
3. Set up WIFI on this router
4. Connect to this WIFI hotspot when I want to access something geo-blocked from my home country

Is there any reason this would not work? Is there a better solution, I should consider?

Is there a certain VPN standard I should be looking for, or would I have to flash the router with a custom firmware (DD-WRT, Tomato etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wifi Access Points which support routing (not juts connecting your Wifi clients to your LAN) such as DD-WR or Mikrotik RouterOS (and much more) allows to setup multiple VPNs. You should focus on your country VPN offerings by VPN providers first (to select protocol). Most popular are PPTP (old), OpenVPN, Wireguard which is new and cool one and supported in recent firmware).

I will go with https://mikrotik.com/product/RBcAP2nD or https://mikrotik.com/product/hap_ac3